gcloud auth print-identity-token for firebase account
I have an App which uses Firebase as a backend including a Google Sign in for the App Users.
For testing purposes I want to generate a curl command which does a lock in into the App using this Google Sign in and for what I understand I can use this command for that:
curl --location 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=...' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data '{ "requestUri": "http://localhost", "postBody": "id_token=<ThisIDTokenGivesMeHeadache>&providerId=google.com", "returnIdpCredential": true, "returnSecureToken": true }' source
OK, the problem is getting this ID token. As far as I understood I can use this command for that: gcloud auth print-identity-token --audiences=<IdOfTheWebClient>
And here is the problem: I have created a Google-Login Method in my Firebase auth Section and it generated me a Web-Client-ID + a Key. Now when I use this id in the "print-identity-token" command I do get a token, but then using this in the REST call I get an error message:
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Invalid Idp Response: the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application. Its audience (OAuth 2.0 client ID) is <aCompletelyDifferentProjectnumber>-<randomString>.apps.googleusercontent.com, which is not authorized to be used in the project with project_number: <myProjectNumber>". "errors": [ { "message": "<sameMessageAsAbove>", "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid" } ] } }
I have generated the token from the GCP shell which is connected to my firebase account, but I think that somewhere here is the error. Because I also tried it from my local machine and there the token contained another projectNumber.
One way out of this I can whitelist this -.apps.googleusercontent.com in my firebase Login section, but I am a bit reluctant in whitelisting any random client ids to login into my system just to "make it work".
